# Parse.com 'Explorer' view custom event counts inconsistent with 'Events' view?

Tags: parse-platform, analytics

I am using the Parse.com REST API to track two kinds of custom events each with up to 3 dimensions.

The 'Custom Breakdown' view of Analytics -> Events (https://www.parse.com/apps/oss-hit-upload-test#events) interface says that I have recorded  1909 of one event type and 805 of the other.  I believe these counts to be correct as they match the input data.

In contrast, Analytics -> Explorer -> 'Make a table' (e.g. https://www.parse.com/apps/oss-hit-upload-test/explorer/559b7ed679bd3e69de000006) is returning only 1,284 rows when I ask it for every custom event.

I am looking at the same time period for both interfaces.

The counts are inconsistent.  Is this a bug or am I using the Explorer interface incorrectly?  I know that within Parse it is only possible to fetch 1,000 records at a time.  Maybe this (or a similar) limitation applies to the Explorer interface?  Or maybe Explorer uses some kind of sampling?

Comment: Once go to Analytics -> Events and check whole analytics requests. To do this go to custom breakdown and set analytics request.

Comment: And also it doesn't has any limitations like 1000 limit

Comment: @Technoid I checked the 'Analytics Requests' report within Analytics -> Events.  It says I made 2716 requests, which matches my expectation.

Comment: According to parse "We only have data going back to January 22, 2015 currently available in the Explorer. We don't currently have plans to backfill old data, but are planning to retain a year's worth of data for use by the Explorer.".
 Is your data older than jan 22??

Comment: @Technoid Nope.  Just uploaded yesterday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, it appears to be a glitch in Explorer.**

I have been able to reproduce the problem using my Parse.com app and following the steps exactly. I receive a much lower than expected number in Parse Explorer. For now, I would trust the Analytics numbers.

FWIW, on one particular event, my counts were 41579 in Analytics and 31848 in Explorer, a ratio of 1.3055. I see that your ratio was around 2.11, which means the problem is more idiosyncratic than a simple difference in how events are recorded. This points to a deeper problem with how Parse's numbers add up.

NOTE: I will ask the Parse team if they have any suggestions and report back.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, Parse has a well-documented way of reporting bugs to their team: https://parse.com/help#report

Comment: This bug looks very similar - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/877622355646661/

Comment: Thanks @HectorRamos! I'll add a report :)

Comment: @HectorRamos - I have confirmed that this bug exists even at very low levels of data (< 10 events).  I see this as quite serious - trustable reports are a foundational feature of any analytics system.  Hard for me to use this product (or recommend it's use) when it can't seem to add things up consistently.

Comment: On the surface this seems like a mismatch between the two queries (are you sure you're using the same timezone? I think the data browser uses your machine's timezone, and the Explorer uses UTC)